# I need QuickReturnView for gridview like sample ListView. Can anyone help me?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

Can anyone have sample about quickreturnview gridview ? I used https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView. but I have a bug when scrolling in gridview. Can you help me ?

Comment: Please post logs and code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use alternative library (alike the one from your question) i.e. this one: https://github.com/allminewuwei/QuickReturnView

What you need to do is: 
 1. Download the library and import it in your workspace (I'm using eclipse terms, to the analog action in Android Studio)
 2. Copy paste the two classes (shown in the screenshot) from the library project in to your project.

[image]

3. It would be neat if you open a separate package (smt like: com.yourapp.quickretrun)
4. resolve the issues (quick fix tips should do the trick)
5. Rename the QuickReturnListView class that you've imported in you project into QuickReturnGridView (or anything that will imply the nature of the widget) and do this change:

   public class QuickReturnGridView extends GridView {

   /*can extend any class that is extended from
    don't change anything else within the class */
   }

   6. Lastly in the layout that you're going to make use of the newly created component, make sure that you follow this hierarchy (must have the exact **layout_width** and **layout_height** values) : 
      [image]